# NavBar Bootstrap 5 Toggle hamburger Menu doesn't show items

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have created a navigation bar using navbar isntructions in Bootstrap 5. I have added a Toggle hamburger Menu and linked it to the list that is to be shown. But when i reduce screen size, the Toggle doesn't work.

My code is below. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->     
  <link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>NavBar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collpase" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- menu items -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Explore</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  
  <!-- Add scripts needed for bootstrap to work -->    
  <script 
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  >
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to implement toggle button in navbar in bootstrap, but I'm unable to get the button to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collpase" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>`

collapse spelling is wrong in button